# Status of Zeeman's collapsability Conjecture

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, discrete-geometry

Zeeman's conjecture  in  topological  combinatorics  states  that if $K$ is a contractible polyhedron of dimension 2, then $K\times I$ has a collapsible subdivision.

What  is  the  status  of  this  conjecture  as  of  2015?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These two very recent surveys state the conjecture as open:

- Robert Kropholler, [Zeeman’s collapsibility conjecture](https://web.archive.org/web/20150918223637/http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/kar/Zeeman.pdf) (2013)
- A. P. M. Kupers, [Zeeman's conjecture](http://math.harvard.edu/~kupers/notes/zeemansconjecture.pdf) (2014)

It doesn't seem like there's been any progress since. In particular, the most important results towards the conjecture are:

(**Cohen**, 1975) If $K$ is a contractible $2$-polyhedron, then $K\times I^6$ is collapsible.  Similarly, if $K$ is a contractible $n$-polyhedron for $n \geq 3$, then $K \times I^{2n}$ is collapsible.

(**Perelman**, 2003, *corollary to the Poincaré conjecture*) Zeeman's conjecture is true for standard $2$-polyhedra that are spines of $3$-manifolds

Comment: There is also this recent result by Adiprasito & Benedetti (2012) [Subdivisions, shellability, and collapsibility of products](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.6606.pdf):  

For any contractible complex $C$ there is an $n\ge  0$ such that $C\times I^n$ is collapsible